# System.Text.Json - Unable to find TokenType Integer, Float, etc

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I'm trying to migrate the following Json.NET `DateTimeConverter` to System.Text.Json.

The issue is that I cannot find `JsonTokenType.Integer` or `JsonTokenType.Float`. There is only `JsonTokenType.Number`.

### System.Text.Json

```cs
public sealed class MillisecondEpochDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?>
{
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    private const long ticksPerSecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;
    private const decimal ticksPerMicrosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000;
    private const decimal ticksPerNanosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000m / 1000;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime) || typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType is JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            var longValue = reader.GetInt64();
            if (longValue is 0 or -1)
            {
                return typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime) ? default(DateTime) : null;
            }

            if (longValue < 19999999999)
            {
                return ConvertFromSeconds(longValue);
            }

            if (longValue < 19999999999999)
            {
                return ConvertFromMilliseconds(longValue);
            }

            if (longValue < 19999999999999999)
            {
                return ConvertFromMicroseconds(longValue);
            }

            return ConvertFromNanoseconds(longValue);
        }

        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteNumberValue(new DateTimeOffset(value).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a seconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="seconds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime ConvertFromSeconds(double seconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(seconds * ticksPerSecond));

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a milliseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="milliseconds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime ConvertFromMilliseconds(double milliseconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(milliseconds * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond));

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a microseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="microseconds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime ConvertFromMicroseconds(long microseconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(microseconds * ticksPerMicrosecond));

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a nanoseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nanoseconds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime ConvertFromNanoseconds(long nanoseconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(nanoseconds * ticksPerNanosecond));

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a DateTime value to seconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="time"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static long? ConvertToSeconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).TotalSeconds);

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a DateTime value to milliseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="time"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static long? ConvertToMilliseconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).TotalMilliseconds);

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a DateTime value to microseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="time"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static long? ConvertToMicroseconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).Ticks / ticksPerMicrosecond);

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a DateTime value to nanoseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="time"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static long? ConvertToNanoseconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).Ticks / ticksPerNanosecond);
}
```

### Original Json.NET code

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CryptoExchange.Net.Converters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Datetime converter. Supports converting from string/long/double to DateTime and back. Numbers are assumed to be the time since 1970-01-01.
    /// </summary>
    public class DateTimeConverter: JsonConverter
    {
        private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        private const long ticksPerSecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;
        private const decimal ticksPerMicrosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000;
        private const decimal ticksPerNanosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000m / 1000;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.Value == null)
                return null;

            if(reader.TokenType is JsonToken.Integer)
            {
                var longValue = (long)reader.Value;
                if (longValue == 0)
                    return objectType == typeof(DateTime) ? default(DateTime): null;
                if (longValue < 1999999999)
                    return ConvertFromSeconds(longValue);
                if (longValue < 1999999999999)
                    return ConvertFromMilliseconds(longValue);
                if (longValue < 1999999999999999)
                    return ConvertFromMicroseconds(longValue);
                
                return ConvertFromNanoseconds(longValue);
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType is JsonToken.Float)
            {
                var doubleValue = (double)reader.Value;
                if (doubleValue < 1999999999)
                    return ConvertFromSeconds(doubleValue);
                
                return ConvertFromMilliseconds(doubleValue);
            }
            else if(reader.TokenType is JsonToken.String)
            {
                var stringValue = (string)reader.Value;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
                    return null;

                if (stringValue.Length == 8)
                {
                    // Parse 20211103 format
                    if (!int.TryParse(stringValue.Substring(0, 4), out var year)
                        || !int.TryParse(stringValue.Substring(4, 2), out var month)
                        || !int.TryParse(stringValue.Substring(6, 2), out var day))
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff} | Warning | Unknown DateTime format: " + reader.Value);
                        return default;
                    }
                    return new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }

                if (stringValue.Length == 6)
                {
                    // Parse 211103 format
                    if (!int.TryParse(stringValue.Substring(0, 2), out var year)
                        || !int.TryParse(stringValue.Substring(2, 2), out var month)
                        || !int.TryParse(stringValue.Substring(4, 2), out var day))
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff} | Warning | Unknown DateTime format: " + reader.Value);
                        return default;
                    }
                    return new DateTime(year + 2000, month, day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }

                if (double.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var doubleValue))
                {
                    // Parse 1637745563.000 format
                    if (doubleValue < 1999999999)
                        return ConvertFromSeconds(doubleValue);
                    if (doubleValue < 1999999999999)
                        return ConvertFromMilliseconds((long)doubleValue);
                    if (doubleValue < 1999999999999999)
                        return ConvertFromMicroseconds((long)doubleValue);

                    return ConvertFromNanoseconds((long)doubleValue);
                }

                if(stringValue.Length == 10)
                {
                    // Parse 2021-11-03 format
                    var values = stringValue.Split('-');
                    if(!int.TryParse(values[0], out var year)
                        || !int.TryParse(values[1], out var month)
                        || !int.TryParse(values[2], out var day))
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff} | Warning | Unknown DateTime format: " + reader.Value);
                        return default;
                    }

                    return new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }

                return DateTime.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
            }
            else if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Date)
            {
                return (DateTime)reader.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff} | Warning | Unknown DateTime format: " + reader.Value);
                return default;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a seconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="seconds"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime ConvertFromSeconds(double seconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(seconds * ticksPerSecond));
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a milliseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="milliseconds"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime ConvertFromMilliseconds(double milliseconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(milliseconds * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond));
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a microseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="microseconds"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime ConvertFromMicroseconds(long microseconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(microseconds * ticksPerMicrosecond));
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a nanoseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value to DateTime
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nanoseconds"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime ConvertFromNanoseconds(long nanoseconds) => _epoch.AddTicks((long)Math.Round(nanoseconds * ticksPerNanosecond));
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a DateTime value to seconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [return: NotNullIfNotNull("time")]
        public static long? ConvertToSeconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null: (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).TotalSeconds);
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a DateTime value to milliseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [return: NotNullIfNotNull("time")]
        public static long? ConvertToMilliseconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a DateTime value to microseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [return: NotNullIfNotNull("time")]
        public static long? ConvertToMicroseconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).Ticks / ticksPerMicrosecond);
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a DateTime value to nanoseconds since epoch (01-01-1970) value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [return: NotNullIfNotNull("time")]
        public static long? ConvertToNanoseconds(DateTime? time) => time == null ? null : (long)Math.Round((time.Value - _epoch).Ticks / ticksPerNanosecond);


        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var datetimeValue = (DateTime?)value;
            if (datetimeValue == null)
                writer.WriteValue((DateTime?)null);
            if(datetimeValue == default(DateTime))
                writer.WriteValue((DateTime?)null);
            else
                writer.WriteValue((long)Math.Round(((DateTime)value! - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All numbers have `JsonToken.Number` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsontokentype?view=net-6.0. JSON is javascript and javascript only have numbers.

Comment: @PoulBak, so I have to figure it out on my own how to detect integer, float, etc.

Comment: Duplicate?  [In a custom JsonConverter, how can I determine whether a Utf8JsonReader numeric token is a decimal or a long?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60907741).

Comment: @dbc yes, it seems like that. You can mark it and thanks